# Compiling VLC on Linux: Error couldnt find Lua

Tags: compilation, vlc

I am trying to compile VLC for Linux. When I run the configure script, I am getting the error message

> configure: error: Could not find lua. Lua is needed for some
>   interfaces (rc, telnet, http) as well as many other custom scripts.
>   Use --disable-lua to ignore this error.

I have lua on my system. I ran  lua -v and got

> Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

whereis lua gives

> /usr/bin/lua /usr/lib/lua /usr/share/lua /usr/share/man/man1/lua.1.gz

Which looks to be a standard location. Any ideas on why configure isn't picking up lua?

Comment: Where should the headers be? I checked in /usr/include/ without luck.

Comment: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=lua-devel

Comment: Thank you it works now.. Please post an answer so  that I can accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by Not_a_Golfer, you need [Lua header/library files](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=lua-devel)

Comment: On Ubuntu the package is called libluaX.Y-dev, e.g. liblua5.2-dev

Answer (score 30):

On Debian based

```
$ apt-get install lua5.2 liblua5.2-dev
```

Worked for me

Comment: I first installed the same but with 5.3 with no luck. With 5.2, it passed indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Fix for **rpm** based systems:

```
sudo dnf install lua-devel
```