# ./configure VLC: LUA not found, even if 'lua -v' works

Tags: lua, path, centos, header-files, vlc

I wanted to install locally VLC on a 6.9 CentOS desktop (at work) to watch [this](http://video.upmc.fr/differe.php?collec=E_C_correction_cours_lp_205_2012&video=2) video. Since **I don't have root access**,  I downloaded the [2.2.6](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/2.2.6/vlc-2.2.6.tar.xz) version in my home folder and ran `configure` as said in `INSTALL`

Then, it failed because Lua wasn't found. So I downloaded the latest version following the method propose by the official website, with `lua -v` working.

I've added the executable and the .h headers (as answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925363/compiling-vlc-on-linux-error-couldnt-find-lua) question) to **my PATH in local `bin` folder**. Then ran `configure` again. Still it cannot find `lua`. Looking at the `configure` script and the `INSTALL` text, I wasn't able to find a solution to make VLC search for Lua in PATH.

So how do I configure my system to makes VLC working ?

Comment: Did you check https://wiki.videolan.org/Compile_VLC ?